# Number of elements in the set of $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: matrices

Let

$$\mathbf{S}_{2\times 2}=\left\{  \left( \begin{matrix} a& b\\ c& d \end{matrix} \right) | a, b, c, d\in\Bbb {Z}_4\right\}$$

be the finite set of $2 \times 2$ matrices, where $\Bbb {Z}_4=\lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3\rbrace$. And each entry of $\mathbf{S}_{2\times 2}$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix of $\Bbb {Z}_4$. What is the number of elements in $\mathbf{S}_{2\times 2}$?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Are you sure that the matrices do not have to be invertible? Otherwise the question is trivial.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I do not see any relevance of the invertibility of the matrices in this question. I just wish to calculate the number of elements in the set $\mathbf{S}_{2\times 2}$ as defined.

Comment: Perhaps. I am sceptical because this is a typical homework for showing that we have a **subgroup** of $GL_2(\Bbb Z_4)$, and what the order of this subgroup is. I apologize if this is not the case. But then the answer is really easy :) That's the same as asking how many quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ we can make if we have $4$ values for each of $a,b,c,d$. No need to use matrices then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ok. So, some  quadruple will have all entries identical e.g., (0, 0, 0), (1,  1, 1)..etc. I think required answer is $4^4$ as already answered.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Please suggest me your answer as how is the answer really easy if the  problem is to find the number of quadruples with the given values {a, b, c, d}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $4$ possibilities for each entry of the matrix and there are $4$ entries. Thus we have a total of $4^4$ possibilities.